# Using ruby variable for class name in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have the piece of code where I am trying to use a variable for a class name in HAML. Here it is:

```
      - data_table(@installation_requests, nil, {:placeholder => ''}) do |installation_request, css_class|
          %tr{:class => css_class}
```

I can't see anything wrong with it, RubyMine IDE doesn't pick an error either, it thinks that it is legitimate use of the variable.  I'm getting the following error:

```
odd number of arguments for Hash
```

Can anyone point me to what's wrong with the code above?

Comment: Do you get the error when you use a string literal instead of the variable?

Comment: Try calling `to_s` on `css_class`.

Comment: Yep the same error.  When I'm just using hardcodeded string instead of variable it works..

Answer (score 7):

What if you try:

```
- data_table(@installation_requests, nil, {:placeholder => ''}) do |installation_request, css_class|
  %tr{:class => "#{css_class}"}
```

or if you are saving your views as view.html.haml:

```
- data_table(@installation_requests, nil, {:placeholder => ''}) do |installation_request, css_class|
  <tr class="#{css_class}">
  ....stuff....
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Hash can actually neatly pass an array passed to it into a sequence of keys and values.

For e.g.:

```
Hash["a", "apple", "b", "boy"]       #=> {"a"=>"apple", "b"=>"boy"}
```

If you pass an odd number of arguments to be splat into key/value pairs...

```
Hash["a", "apple", "b", "boy", "c"]  #=> odd number of arguments for Hash
```

So, I am pretty sure this is happening somewhere inside the `data_table` method. So, please check if an array is being splat into Hash somewhere in the sequence of function calls!

Comment: If this happens, then calling css_class.class would return 'Array', but it returns 'String'...

Comment: What version of Ruby and HAML are you using? See this issue: https://github.com/nex3/haml/issues/388